# Browserify + NodeJS : Not working

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am new to Node and Browserify. Rightnow I am struggling hard and can't get my browserify code running. Kindly find below my files. Problem is that when I open the index.html file directly into the browser then, it works as expected and prints - 'pizza is extremely yummy'. But when I run app.js in node with :
node app.js

and open the URL(localhost:8080) in the browser than nothing appears in the Browser Console. Also when I look into the source of the URL through browser's 'View Source' option, then the file './bundle.js' is blank
I am not able to understand why 
*) What's going behind the scene
*) Why Browser Console is blank
*) Why the 'bundler.js' file is empty in case it's served by node.

Thanks

---

### index.js

```
// require the core node events module
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

//create a new event emitter
var emitter = new EventEmitter;

// set up a listener for the event
emitter.on('pizza', function(message){
  console.log(message);
});

// emit an event
emitter.emit('pizza', 'pizza is extremely yummy');
```

---

### app.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var fs = require('fs');


app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
```

---

### index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>node / browserify example</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### bundle.js

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
// require the core node events module
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

//create a new event emitter
var emitter = new EventEmitter;

// set up a listener for the event
emitter.on('pizza', function(message){
  console.log(message);
});

// emit an event
emitter.emit('pizza', 'pizza is extremely yummy');

},{"events":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
// Copyright Joyent, Inc. and other Node contributors.
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
// copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
// "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
// without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
// distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit
// persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the
// following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
// in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
// OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
// MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN
// NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM,
// DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR
// OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE
// USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

function EventEmitter() {
  this._events = this._events || {};
  this._maxListeners = this._maxListeners || undefined;
}
module.exports = EventEmitter;

// Backwards-compat with node 0.10.x
EventEmitter.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;

EventEmitter.prototype._events = undefined;
EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = undefined;

// By default EventEmitters will print a warning if more than 10 listeners are
// added to it. This is a useful default which helps finding memory leaks.
EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 10;

// Obviously not all Emitters should be limited to 10. This function allows
// that to be increased. Set to zero for unlimited.
EventEmitter.prototype.setMaxListeners = function(n) {
  if (!isNumber(n) || n < 0 || isNaN(n))
    throw TypeError('n must be a positive number');
  this._maxListeners = n;
  return this;
};

EventEmitter.prototype.emit = function(type) {
  var er, handler, len, args, i, listeners;

  if (!this._events)
    this._events = {};

  // If there is no 'error' event listener then throw.
  if (type === 'error') {
    if (!this._events.error ||
        (isObject(this._events.error) && !this._events.error.length)) {
      er = arguments[1];
      if (er instanceof Error) {
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      }
      throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
    }
  }

  handler = this._events[type];

  if (isUndefined(handler))
    return false;

  if (isFunction(handler)) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
      // fast cases
      case 1:
        handler.call(this);
        break;
      case 2:
        handler.call(this, arguments[1]);
        break;
      case 3:
        handler.call(this, arguments[1], arguments[2]);
        break;
      // slower
      default:
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        handler.apply(this, args);
    }
  } else if (isObject(handler)) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    listeners = handler.slice();
    len = listeners.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
      listeners[i].apply(this, args);
  }

  return true;
};

EventEmitter.prototype.addListener = function(type, listener) {
  var m;

  if (!isFunction(listener))
    throw TypeError('listener must be a function');

  if (!this._events)
    this._events = {};

  // To avoid recursion in the case that type === "newListener"! Before
  // adding it to the listeners, first emit "newListener".
  if (this._events.newListener)
    this.emit('newListener', type,
              isFunction(listener.listener) ?
              listener.listener : listener);

  if (!this._events[type])
    // Optimize the case of one listener. Don't need the extra array object.
    this._events[type] = listener;
  else if (isObject(this._events[type]))
    // If we've already got an array, just append.
    this._events[type].push(listener);
  else
    // Adding the second element, need to change to array.
    this._events[type] = [this._events[type], listener];

  // Check for listener leak
  if (isObject(this._events[type]) && !this._events[type].warned) {
    if (!isUndefined(this._maxListeners)) {
      m = this._maxListeners;
    } else {
      m = EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners;
    }

    if (m && m > 0 && this._events[type].length > m) {
      this._events[type].warned = true;
      console.error('(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory ' +
                    'leak detected. %d listeners added. ' +
                    'Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.',
                    this._events[type].length);
      if (typeof console.trace === 'function') {
        // not supported in IE 10
        console.trace();
      }
    }
  }

  return this;
};

EventEmitter.prototype.on = EventEmitter.prototype.addListener;

EventEmitter.prototype.once = function(type, listener) {
  if (!isFunction(listener))
    throw TypeError('listener must be a function');

  var fired = false;

  function g() {
    this.removeListener(type, g);

    if (!fired) {
      fired = true;
      listener.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }

  g.listener = listener;
  this.on(type, g);

  return this;
};

// emits a 'removeListener' event iff the listener was removed
EventEmitter.prototype.removeListener = function(type, listener) {
  var list, position, length, i;

  if (!isFunction(listener))
    throw TypeError('listener must be a function');

  if (!this._events || !this._events[type])
    return this;

  list = this._events[type];
  length = list.length;
  position = -1;

  if (list === listener ||
      (isFunction(list.listener) && list.listener === listener)) {
    delete this._events[type];
    if (this._events.removeListener)
      this.emit('removeListener', type, listener);

  } else if (isObject(list)) {
    for (i = length; i-- > 0;) {
      if (list[i] === listener ||
          (list[i].listener && list[i].listener === listener)) {
        position = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (position < 0)
      return this;

    if (list.length === 1) {
      list.length = 0;
      delete this._events[type];
    } else {
      list.splice(position, 1);
    }

    if (this._events.removeListener)
      this.emit('removeListener', type, listener);
  }

  return this;
};

EventEmitter.prototype.removeAllListeners = function(type) {
  var key, listeners;

  if (!this._events)
    return this;

  // not listening for removeListener, no need to emit
  if (!this._events.removeListener) {
    if (arguments.length === 0)
      this._events = {};
    else if (this._events[type])
      delete this._events[type];
    return this;
  }

  // emit removeListener for all listeners on all events
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    for (key in this._events) {
      if (key === 'removeListener') continue;
      this.removeAllListeners(key);
    }
    this.removeAllListeners('removeListener');
    this._events = {};
    return this;
  }

  listeners = this._events[type];

  if (isFunction(listeners)) {
    this.removeListener(type, listeners);
  } else if (listeners) {
    // LIFO order
    while (listeners.length)
      this.removeListener(type, listeners[listeners.length - 1]);
  }
  delete this._events[type];

  return this;
};

EventEmitter.prototype.listeners = function(type) {
  var ret;
  if (!this._events || !this._events[type])
    ret = [];
  else if (isFunction(this._events[type]))
    ret = [this._events[type]];
  else
    ret = this._events[type].slice();
  return ret;
};

EventEmitter.prototype.listenerCount = function(type) {
  if (this._events) {
    var evlistener = this._events[type];

    if (isFunction(evlistener))
      return 1;
    else if (evlistener)
      return evlistener.length;
  }
  return 0;
};

EventEmitter.listenerCount = function(emitter, type) {
  return emitter.listenerCount(type);
};

function isFunction(arg) {
  return typeof arg === 'function';
}

function isNumber(arg) {
  return typeof arg === 'number';
}

function isObject(arg) {
  return typeof arg === 'object' && arg !== null;
}

function isUndefined(arg) {
  return arg === void 0;
}

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

---

Comment: I have figured out the problem - it's because of using the hard-coded file name in the app.js above(line : 9). I should have used '__dirname + req.url' instead of '__dirname + '/index.html''... It was a silly mistake from me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is passing through Node.js, even the static file. It must have a route associated with it. Everything is intepreted through app.js so static files just don't work like you may expect if you are used to static development with html files.

I recommend setting up express and do a static route for your bundle.js file.

http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks Jason, 
Definitely I'll go with express. But as for the above, I have figured out the problem - it's because of using the hard-coded file name in the app.js above(line : 9). I should have used '__dirname + req.url' instead of '__dirname + '/index.html''... It was a silly mistake from me!

Comment: That was a clever idea

Comment: The only problem with that solution is people can get at any file I believe and see source, etc. But using something like a public folder that you map static files to will be safer in terms of knowing specifically what is OK to view. But smart otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, I am working on it. You showed me the right path. Thanks a lot Jason.